# Как задать цикл правильно в моем случае?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
List = ['011001110010000','100010111000000'] #по 15 символов
for i in List:
    n1 = i
    schot = 0
    schot1 = 0
    schot2 = 0
    schot3 = 0
    schot4 = 0
    schot5 = 0
    for x in n1:
        schot1 = (int(n1[8 + int(x)]) + int(n1[9 + int(x)]) + int(n1[11 + int(x)]))%2
        schot2 = (int(n1[12 + int(x)]) + int(n1[13 + int(x)]) + int(n1[4 + int(x)]))%2
        schot3 = (int(n1[14 + int(x)]) + int(n1[2 + int(x)]) + int(n1[6 + int(x)]))%2
        schot4 = (int(n1[1 + int(x)]) + int(n1[3 + int(x)]) + int(n1[7 + int(x)]))%2
        schot5 = (int(x))
        schot = schot1+ schot2+ schot3+ schot4+ schot5
        if (schot => 3):
            n1[x] = '1'
        else:
            n1[x] = '0'
```

Например когда i=5, int(n1[14 + int(x)]),не стало 19,а стало 4. Применить schot1,2,3,4,5 для каждого элемента, и сделать новый лист по 15.

Comment: мне кажется вы изобретаете велосипед, бизнес задача какая?

Comment: Это не бизнес задача, мажоритарное декодирование

Comment: Исправьте код. В нем слишком много скобок и не хватает кавычек.

Comment: Исправил скобки, кавычки где? В условии поставить?

Comment: В первой строчке в списке второй элемент не закрыт. Запустите код, вам сразу все напишет.

Comment: Сделано. Как сделать цикл когда больше 14 , он продолжил с 0

Comment: Это мажоритарное декодирование.Каждая цифра каждого элемента проверяется 5ю уравнениями. В этом случае schot1,2,3,4,5. Для первого числа первого элемента с - это место где находится цифры и берет значение. schot1= (с8+с9+с11)%2, schot2=(c12+c13+c+4)%2, schot3=(c14+c2+c6)%2, schot4=(c1+c3+c7)%2, schot5=(c0) . Потом эти schot1,2,3,4,5 просто суммируется. Если сумма больше либо равно 3, то вместо первой цифры ставим 1, если меньше то ставим 0. И до 7 цифры каждого элемента. Проблема в том , что для следующих цифр с увеличивается на 1 с8 на с9 итд. когда с14, то начинается с 0.

Answer (score 0):

Нужно взять остаток от деления на 15. Например, для самого первого случая:

```
int(n1[(8 + int(x))%15]
```

Comment: Мне непонятен смысл этого комментария... Я рассказал, как "сделать цикл когда больше 14 , он продолжил с 0".

Comment: У меня есть исходный данный 011001110010000 15символов. Проверяем 1 символа: Сi(1) = C8+i C9+i + C11+i. Ci(2) = C12+i + C13+i + C4+i. Ci(3) = C14+i + C2+i + C6+i. Ci(4) = C1+i + C3+i + C7+i. Ci(5) = Ci

Comment: Все суммы по модулю 2. И сумма е результатов больше либо равно 3, то первый элемент исходного данного заменяется на 1, если меньше то на 0.

Comment: Я имел ввиду например когда i = 6 С14+i  взял число С5 то есть 6ой цифр с исходного данного

Comment: Сумма всех 5 не берет по модулю 2

Comment: Я же написал, что нужно сделать - индекс по модулю 15.

Comment: В коде написано что берется по модулю, а что не берется